Data request from former job
I recently transitioned from a research institution where I worked for four years as a postdoctoral researcher on two major projects. One of these projects has been published, and the other is currently being prepared for submission.
I have received a request from a postdoc who has taken over my previous role on secondary research, asking for manuscripts and raw figures (in Illustrator format) that I worked on. I'm concerned about how much data I should share, particularly because I want to maintain my authorship rights and ensure that any future negotiations about authorship are not compromised.
To give you a bit more context, the culture at my previous institution was extremely hierarchical and not very supportive. During my tenure, I encountered numerous issues with authorship on research projects. Initially, I was involved in a primary research project and was promised first authorship. However, the PIs frequently changed their stance on authorship rankings. I eventually stepped away from this project to focus on a second project, where I developed novel experimental methods and setups for ephys. The primary project was initially submitted for publication and rejected, with me being listed as the eighth author. The PIs then requested me to apply the newly established methods to add impactful data for the first project, once again promising me the first author position. Despite my significant contributions and fulfilling their additional requests, I was relegated to third author. I later learned that the postdoc who secured the first author position had insisted on not sharing this status and had advocated for her favored student to be the second author. I discovered this demotion through conversations with other colleagues. After hearing this, I confronted the PIs, which resulted in a big argument where they even threatened to strip my authorship from another research project.
This experience made it impossible for me to stay, and I started looking for another postdoc position. Unsurprisingly, they didn’t give me a recommendation letter and even spoke poorly of me to the PI who contacted them for a reference. I managed to secure another position thanks to the support of my former graduate school mentors.
Given these experiences, I am now quite cautious about sharing data, fearing potential misuse or further conflicts. Currently, the team at my former institution has requested access to manuscripts, figures (and raw data in future I guess), presumably to continue the work without my involvement, predicted from the way they say in the email. I am uncertain about the appropriateness of sharing these resources. Given the background, I worry about the implications for my rights and the recognition of my contributions.
How much should I realistically share without compromising my rights and previous contributions? If anyone has navigated a similar situation or has insights on protecting one’s academic work and authorship rights, your advice would be immensely valuable.
Thank you for your guidance.

Has the previous work been published with you as an author? Is there a public record of you as a contributor, say at arXiv?

I'm having a hard time understanding why you're considering it at all based on the context you've provided. Are those materials part of a project your previous employers contributed to and which you intend to publish with them? If they are all things only you worked on, they are yours. If they contain other people's contributions, it sounds to me like you should refuse, cut your losses, and move on to other projects if at all possible.

Yes one of the two research that I was involved in is publicated currently, and I am a little bit afraid of shairing the exact information.
As I worked the project from the funding of the institute, they can say that supported the second research. I would like to publicate it with them, but I know that once I share the raw data source they will be able to easily throw me away. So for me, the best scenario will be wisely responding to them so they have to keep working with me. I am wondering sharing how and to which point will make it possible.

Holding data hostage is poor form, and depending on the source of funding for the work (not just your salary, but the facilities and resources used) and the specific rules of your country/region/university could be illegal. So you could also be in the wrong in this situation. It sounds very much like you could be. You can abstain from sharing your interpretation (and other creative derivation), but data which you were paid to collect while there is another.
Your only appropriate recourse is to release the data obtained at that institution as it does not belong to you. If your contribution rises to the level of authorship, when published, you should be included. If you are not included then you can raise ethics complaints.
However, your current approach of doing something unethical and potentially illegal to prevent your former colleagues from doing something else that is also unethical is not very smart. You are both wrong for slightly different reasons.

If anything, if I had a colleague behaving as suspiciously as OP I'd probably want to redo the whole thing from scratch anyways and cut them out that way, not to punish them for not sharing the data but because I would be too suspicious of fraud for it to have any value to me at all.

@BryanKrause I had to do a similar thing with a grad student in my early days. They left (very unhappy about things mostly stemming from personal life issues which spilled into poor interactions with other students in the department), and while they had sent me the data interpretation, they did not release the raw data, and their lab book did not correlate properly to the instrument files. So a new student had to repeat all of the work anyway, which led to slightly different/better data. I still gave authorship to the former grad student, but I would have been within my rights to refuse.

Yeah, to clarify my comment, if they'd earned authorship anyways then they're an author, period. But it's quite possible that by not contributing data or analysis to the project they'd no longer qualify if that was to be their main contribution and they've ceased to participate.

Thank you for the comment. I understand your point, and I also determined to share the data. But what I am worried about is how should I behave towards people who are expected to behave in unethical way, without compromising my own ethical and legal obligations. This concern arises from past experiences where my contributions were undervalued and my authorship rights were compromised. As I have done at least 70% of the work and created the figures for the paper, I just want to ensure that my rights are properly recognized.

@postdoc0115 Unfortunately you cannot withhold things preemptively based on any assumption that the receiving party will act unethically (or unfavorably towards you). You have to follow the process and seek correction after an impropriety has occurred, and not behave as if one is about to occur (even if likely). What you can do is seek to work with people whose operational standards align with yours, and if you find yourself in certain situations, you may have to just move on. Sometimes that means cutting your losses and focusing on positive momentum going forward.
